# Redis sizing for Production

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis, spring-data-redis

I have few queries regarding Redis Cluster setup:
1.Does redis support cross site replication ? When we start redis cluster,can we decide what will be the slave of each instance.
2.I need to store around 11  billion keys,with full persistance and fault tolerance,how many master -slaves should i start with? I have a high tps requirement of both read and writes.

Pls suggest.

Comment: Only you can answer this question, through benchmarking. No possible way to get an objective answer to sizing and number of nodes. As for replication? That's all in the redis docs. Off-topic.

Comment: @David..Please answer point no1 .

Comment: A quick search of `"redis replication"` gets you to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Data is important for you and you don't want to lose any data during failover/DR scenarios.

1. You need to create a Redis cluster.
2. Redis cluster needs **at least** 3 master nodes which shares 16384 slots between each other.
3. You need to create slave nodes as much as you want to replicate data from master nodes.(Please consider right slave number by yourself.)